Does StoreKit filter unsupported product types for older App versions?
I am new to StoreKit and IAP. I am developing version 1.0 of my app, where I plan to offer non-consumable items, with intentions to introduce auto-renewable subscriptions in the upcoming version 2.0. According to App Store review requirements, whenever I add a new type of item in the app, I also need to submit the app version for review.
I want to know, after adding auto-renewable subscription items in App Store Connect for use in version 2.0, will these new items appear when my version 1.0 queries product information through the StoreKit API? If they do appear, since version 1.0 does not support auto-renewable subscriptions, should I add compatibility code to ignore these unsupported items?
Ideally, StoreKit would help filter out product types that are not supported by older app versions, as per App Store requirements for submitting a new app version along with product types. However, I wonder if this is actually the case?
I've already asked this question on Apple's Developer Forum but didn't get a response, so I'd appreciate any help you can offer here. Thank you!

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
The available APIs to query product information from the App Store require you do pass a list of product IDs. By changing this list of product IDs, you decide what products are visible in your app.
As long as you don’t pass a list of non existing product IDs which you create later, your version 1.0 won’t show the auto-renewables. Although, the App Store ignores product IDs for which it has no information, I don’t recommend doing this.
Besides that, I recommend keeping the feature unlocking from version 1.0 in 2.0 so users who spend money in the previous version aren’t disadvantaged.
